# How to get a main (window?) UIView in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap app, extending it with native stuff.

I can make an UIView like this:

```
[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]]
```

and show some stuff like ActionSheets here. But the [MBProgressHUD](http://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD) doesn't show up in this view.

So how do I get the main view (or the PhoneGap's WebView)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woohoo! Solved it by defining a global with the UIWebView which I can access in the app delegate's webViewDidStartLoad.